# Saving EAV Model Causes SQL 1452 Error

Tags: database, model, sql, eav, resource-model

I've recently started learning about creating EAV models. It's been quite the ride so far. Although I feel I'm very close right now.

Currently I have created a "Vendor" EAV Model, but when I try to save the model it throws an SQL 1452 Error:

`` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`dh_onsite_vendor_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_DH_ONSITE_VENDOR_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_), query was: INSERT INTO `dh_onsite_vendor_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, '2017-01-17 21:40:04', '2017-01-17 21:40:04') ``

What I've found to be the problem is that Magento isn't automatically adding the correct values into `entity_type_id` and `attribute_set_id`.

Here is code that throws the error:

```
$test = Mage::getModel('onsite/vendor');
$test->setLabel('Hello World');

$test->save();
```

Here is code that doesn't throw the error:

```
$test = Mage::getModel('onsite/vendor');
$test->setLabel('Hello World');
$test->setAttributeSetId(9);
$test->setEntityId(10);

$test->save();
```

I realized this because I was able to create a record by setting this myself.

Please let me know if you need anymore information from me.

Answer (score 0):

your main entity table contains a FK to the `attribute_set` table.
And you cannot create a record in your table without a valid `attribute_set_id`.

You should be able to add this using the code below before saving a new entity instance.

```
$test->setAttributeSetId($test->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
```

if you implemented your eav entity similar to the core ones.

Comment: Thanks! Is there not a way to do this automatically? With the tutorial I was following they weren't required to set the AttributeSetId or EntityTypeId

Or would this go into `_beforeSave()`?

How can I set the `default_attribute_set_id`?

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/

 At the end they aren't required to manually set the attribute set id

Comment: I tried setting the default attribute set id, but that didn't work. Still receiving the same answer

Answer (score 0):

After more digging in Magento's Core I found that some models were not setting `attribute_set_id` as a foreign key.

Now, this doesn't necessarily solve my problem. A solution would be to set the `attribute_set_id` to the default whenever saving, but I wasn't sure how to accomplish that and I've realized that it's not important for what I need.

So, this solution is working fine for me.